# select column name with special character (ó)

Tags: php, ms-access, pdo

I use PDO to connect a ms-access database where I have a column called `Instalación`:

```
$db = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; Dbq=my/path/to/file.mdb");
$str="SELECT * FROM table";
$qr=$db->query($str);
if( $qr != false){
    while($result=$qr->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        print_r($result);
    }
}
else{
    print_r($db->errorInfo());
}
```

I got something like this : `[Instalaci�n] => DHg` wich I solved using utf8_encode()  so it became (`[Instalación] => DHg`)

my problem is the following:
 when I change the string query to `select Instalación from table`, the `$db->query($str)` return `false`

I tried a few things by changing `$str`, here are the associated errors :

**Error #1**

what I did

`select Instalación from table` or `select [Instalación] from table`

error I got:

```
[0] => 07002
[1] => -3010
[2] => [Microsoft][Controlador ODBC Microsoft Access] Pocos par�metros. Se esperaba 1. (SQLExecute[-3010] at ext\pdo_odbc\odbc_stmt.c:254)
[3] => 07002
```

**Error #2**

what I did:

```
$quoted=$db->quote('Instalación');
$str="select $quoted from table";
```

error I got:

```
[0] => 42000
[1] => 0
[2] => [Microsoft][Controlador ODBC Microsoft Access] La instrucci�n SELECT incluye una palabra reservada, le falta un argumento o est� mal escrito, o bien los signos de puntuaci�n no son correctos. (SQLPrepare[0] at ext\pdo_odbc\odbc_driver.c:206)
[3] =>
```

**Error #3**

what I did:

`SELECT \'Instalación\' from caudal`

error I got:

```
[0] => 42000
[1] => 0
[2] => [Microsoft][Controlador ODBC Microsoft Access] Error de sintaxis (falta operador) en la expresi�n de consulta '\'Instalación\''. (SQLPrepare[0] at ext\pdo_odbc\odbc_driver.c:206)
[3] =>
```

As you can see I ran out of idea to face the problem. Could you help me with that?
I also find wierd that I got rendering problems when displaying errors...

Comment: You can try changing the encoding of your PHP source file to `Windows-1252` (e.g., "Encode in ANSI" in Notepad++) so that PDO_ODBC and the Access ODBC driver can agree on the character encoding of `'Instalación'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the same error, I think you php source file is `UTF8` encoded and you are trying to open a access db that usually works with `ISO-8859-1`.

To run your query you must convert your string:

```
    $db = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; Dbq=my/path/to/file.mdb");
    //$str="SELECT * FROM table";

    $utf8_sql = 'SELECT [Instalación] FROM Table1'; // file must be UTF-8 encoded
    $iso88591_1 = utf8_decode($utf8_sql);
    $iso88591_2 = iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1', $utf8_sql);
    $iso88591_sql = mb_convert_encoding($utf8_sql, 'ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8');



    $qr=$db->query($iso88591_sql);
    if( $qr != false){
        while($result=$qr->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            print_r($result);
        }
    }
    else{
        print_r($db->errorInfo());
    }
```

Comment: thank you for your time but I am not able to test it anymore, it was a problem that I faced during my internship and I am not able to test your solution :/
Let's hope someone else will face the same problem and will be happy to see your solution :)

Comment: well... I have tested my solution, but not problem... when you have a change to test feel free to mark my answer as accepted. Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot @IvanCachicatari! So simple, yet I've been struggling with this for a few days now!