# HTML Error on using special characters in ms-access column name and PDO

Tags: php, ms-access, pdo, special-characters

I have to create a webtool using an inherited database in ms-access. In this database there's a table with some columns containing a `°` in the name (e.g. `BV Totale enterobacteriaceae 37°C`).

database_connection.php:

```
<?php
    $dbName = 'path/to/file';

    if (! file_exists( $dbName )) {
        die("Could not find database file.");
    }

    try {
        $dbConnection = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; Dbq=$dbName; charset=utf8");
        $dbConnection -> exec("set names utf8");

        $dbConnection -> setAttribute( PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND, 'SET NAMES utf8mb4');
        $dbConnection -> setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING );
        $dbConnection -> setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        print "Error: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
        die();
    }
?>
```

get_data.php

```
<?php
    include_once 'database_connection.php';

    // Prepare queries
    $query  =  "SELECT m.[BV Total enterobacteriaceae 37°C] AS Enterobacteriaceae37".
                " FROM Monster m ".
                " WHERE m.[Client ID] = ?".
                ";";

    $result = $dbConnection->prepare( $query );
    $result->bindParam(1, $clientId );

    $clientId = $_SESSION['name'];
    $result->execute();

    $result_table = '';

    while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

        $result_table = $result_table . "<tr class='analysisHead'>";
        $result_table = $result_table .     "<td>". utf8_encode($row['Enterobacteriaceae37'])."</td>";
        $result_table = $result_table . "</tr>";
    }

    echo $result_table;
?>
```

display_data.php

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <style type="text/css">
            table {
                border-collapse: collapse;
            }

            table, th, td {
                border: 1px solid black;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th> Enterobacteriaceae 37°C </th>
            </tr>
            <?php include_once 'get_data.php';?>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is the error I get on the HTML page displaying the data:

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[07002]: COUNT field incorrect: -3010 [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 2. (SQLExecute[-3010] at ext\pdo_odbc\odbc_stmt.c:254)' in C:\wamp64\www\path\to\display_data.php on line 14
( ! ) PDOException: SQLSTATE[07002]: COUNT field incorrect: -3010 [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 2. (SQLExecute[-3010] at ext\pdo_odbc\odbc_stmt.c:254) in C:\wamp64\www\path\to\display_data.php on line 14
```

Using any other column without `°` works perfectly, so it has something to do with this special character. 
Changing the database is not possible, as it is used by other software as well. 
How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Perhaps build and save a query object in Access that applies an alias name to that bizarre field. Then your code references that query. Bad idea to use spaces, punctuation (underscore only exception), special characters in names.

Comment: For future reference, this question got me on the right track: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36620867/select-column-name-with-special-character-%C3%B3